# matlab 3d mesh and line plotting

Tags: matlab

I need help plotting a spiral helix on a cone. For the helix:

```
x = tsin(6t)
y = tcos(6t)
z = t/3
```

...and this helix lies on the cone:

```
z = sqrt(x^2+y^2)/3
```

I need to plot the mesh plot of the cone and the 3D line plot of the helix on the same
chart.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want a surface plot of the cone first.  Try

```
[X Y] = meshgrid(-1:.01:1);
Z = sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2)/3;
```

Then, plot this surface with the `surf` function, and set some sort of shading and transparency

```
surf(X,Y,Z), caxis([-1 1]), shading flat, alpha(.5);
```

This should make a cone shape (you can play with the colors).

Now for the helix, define the vectors as you did

```
t = 0:.01:1;
x = t.*cos(6*t);
y = t.*sin(6*t);
z = t/3;
```

Then do

```
hold on;
```

This makes it so any other plotting you do will appear on the same figure.

Then finally,

```
plot3(x,y,z);
```